# Does ScanSnap S300M have storage capability?

Tags: scanner, document-scanning

Does [ScanSnap S300M](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/services/computing/peripherals/scanners/scansnap/s300m.html) keeps copies of items that I've copied via it, and, if so, how I can access them? For example 
if I've used it to copy & then print a page (and did not save it on my computer), can I later go back and re-print it?

Answer (score 0):

The product site does not mention any storage capability so I doubt you will be able to retrieve what you scanned and printed without storing on you machine.
Although it is possible that a copy of the printed document is still lying in your temporary files folder.